# Can MMA recognize special polynomials as solutions of differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve a system of 2 coupled differential equations.

```
eqna = ((m*c^2)/(h*L) - Sin[z])*Cos[z]*g[z] + (c/L)*
   Cos[z]*(f'[z] + Sin[z]*f[z]) == (A/(i*h))*f[z]

eqnb = ((m*c^2)/(h*L) - Sin[z])*Cos[z]*f[z] - (c/L)*
   Cos[z]*(g'[z] - Sin[z]*g[z]) == (A/(i*h))*g[z]

DSolve[{eqna, eqnb}, {f[z], g[z]}, z]
```

Mathematica doesn't give me any solution here. It is my hope that I can reduce the equation to the definition equation of a known polynomial (e.g. Laguerre) by substitution. So here is my question:

Is Mathematica able to do this as well or do I have to find a substituion first and then consult Mathematica again? How would you approach this problem?

Comment: Try series solution is best you can do for this. something like `AsymptoticDSolveValue[{eqna, eqnb}, {f[z], g[z]}, {z, 0, 5}]`

Comment: @Nasser: Unfortunately, `AsymptoticDSolveValue[{eqna, eqnb}, {f[z], g[z]}, {z, Infinity, 2}]` fails.

Comment: Maple also fails with dsolving it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!